# How can I best handle WPF radio buttons?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I've got some RadioButtons in my XAML...

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Name="RadioButton1" GroupName="Buttons" Click="ButtonsChecked" IsChecked="True">One</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Name="RadioButton2" GroupName="Buttons" Click="ButtonsChecked">Two</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Name="RadioButton3" GroupName="Buttons" Click="ButtonsChecked">Three</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

And I can handle their click events in the Visual Basic code.  This works...

```
    Private Sub ButtonsChecked(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                               ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        Select Case CType(sender, RadioButton).Name
            Case "RadioButton1"
                'Do something one
                Exit Select
            Case "RadioButton2"
                'Do something two
                Exit Select
            Case "RadioButton3"
                'Do something three
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End Sub
```

But, I'd like to improve it.  This code fails...

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Name="RadioButton1" GroupName="Buttons" Click="ButtonsChecked" Command="one" IsChecked="True">One</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Name="RadioButton2" GroupName="Buttons" Click="ButtonsChecked" Command="two">Two</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Name="RadioButton3" GroupName="Buttons" Click="ButtonsChecked" Command="three">Three</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

```
    Private Sub ButtonsChecked(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                               ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        Select Case CType(sender, RadioButton).Command
            Case "one"
                'Do something one
                Exit Select
            Case "two"
                'Do something two
                Exit Select
            Case "three"
                'Do something three
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End Sub
```

In my XAML I get a blue squiggly underline on the **Command=** attributes and this tip...

```
'CommandValueSerializer' ValueSerializer cannot convert from 'System.String'.
```

In my VB I get a green squiggly underline on the **Select Case** line and this warning...

```
Runtime errors might occur when converting 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' to 'String'.
```

Even better would be to use Enum type commands with full Intellisense and compile errors rather than runtime errors in case of typos.  How can I improve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order for commands to work you need to set up bindings in either your xaml or code behind. These command bindings must reference public static fields that have been previously declared.

Then in your buttons Command attribute you will then need to also reference these same commands.

```
<Window 
    x:Class="RadioButtonCommandSample.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadioButtonCommandSample"
    Title="Window1" 
    Height="300" 
    Width="300"
    >
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Window1.CommandOne}" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Window1.CommandTwo}" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Window1.CommandThree}" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton Name="RadioButton1" GroupName="Buttons" Command="{x:Static local:Window1.CommandOne}" IsChecked="True">One</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="RadioButton2" GroupName="Buttons" Command="{x:Static local:Window1.CommandTwo}">Two</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="RadioButton3" GroupName="Buttons" Command="{x:Static local:Window1.CommandThree}">Three</RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public static readonly RoutedCommand CommandOne = new RoutedCommand();
    public static readonly RoutedCommand CommandTwo = new RoutedCommand();
    public static readonly RoutedCommand CommandThree = new RoutedCommand();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Command == CommandOne)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CommandOne");
        }
        else if (e.Command == CommandTwo)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CommandTwo");
        }
        else if (e.Command == CommandThree)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CommandThree");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this, but when I load my page, I cannot select any of them. Is there anyway to enable selecting RadioButtons?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem could be, I just ran this sample and I was able to select the radio buttons ok.

Comment: If all the radio buttons are disabled, then my guess would be that the command bindings failed to, er, bind.

Answer (score 0):

**Better Solution using WPF MVVM Design Pattern:**

Radio Button Control XAML to Modelview.vb/ModelView.cs :

```
XAML Code:
<RadioButton Content="On" IsEnabled="True" IsChecked="{Binding OnJob}"/>
<RadioButton Content="Off" IsEnabled="True" IsChecked="{Binding OffJob}"/>
```

ViewModel.vb :

```
Private _OffJob As Boolean = False
Private _OnJob As Boolean = False

Public Property OnJob As Boolean
    Get
        Return _OnJob
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        Me._OnJob = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property OffJob As Boolean
    Get
        Return _OffJob
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        Me._OffJob = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub FindCheckedItem()
  If(Me.OnJob = True)
    MessageBox.show("You have checked On")
 End If
If(Me.OffJob = False)
 MessageBox.Show("You have checked Off")
End sub
```

One can use the same logic above to see if you checked any of the three Radio 
Buttons viz. Option One, Option Two, Option Three. But checking if the Boolean set id true or false you can identify whether the radio button is checked or not.