# Nested Stackpanel Button Not working

Tags: wpf, button, stackpanel, groupbox

I have a button nested inside two stack panels as shown by this code.

```
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{StaticResource AutomaticUISettings}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!--Header-->
                    <Label Content="If Max UI value is met" />

                    <!--Max UI Value Met Help-->
                    <Button Content="[?]" Command="{Binding ShowMaxValueMetHelp}" Margin="5" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="10">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>

                <!--Options-->
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMaxUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MaxMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Stop}" 
                            Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Stop" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMaxUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MaxMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RollOver}" 
                            Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Roll over to zero" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMaxUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MaxMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RollOvertoMin}" 
                            Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Roll over to Min UI value" Margin="10,0" />
            </StackPanel>
```

The whole thing is in a `Grid` in a `GroupBox` of a `UserControl`. 
The "Max UI Value Met Help" button is not working when clicked. I have similar help buttons to this in a `Grid` above this `StackPanel` that work just fine. I tried to copy and paste those in by this and they don't work either.

Why won't this button work?

**Update:**
I had to switch to a Grid and separate the label & button from the stack of Radio buttons to get it to work, but I want to understand why this didn't work.

The button here is in the same DataContext as the rest of my UserControl. I have multiple help buttons throughout this UserControl and they work, but this one doesn't. It doesn't matter which one I put in there either. I can move the specific button to another location and it works.

I don't like fixing something without understanding why I had to do that.

New Code:

```
            <!--If Max UI is Met-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
                <!--Header-->
                <Label Content="If Max UI value is met" />

                <!--Max UI Value Met Help-->
                <Button Content="[?]" Command="{Binding ShowMaxValueMetHelp}" Margin="5" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="10">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>

            <!--Options-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"  DataContext="{StaticResource AutomaticUISettings}">
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMaxUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MaxMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Stop}" 
                        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Stop" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMaxUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MaxMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RollOver}" 
                        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Roll over to zero" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMaxUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MaxMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RollOvertoMin}" 
                        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Roll over to Min UI value" Margin="10,0" />
            </StackPanel>
```

Here is what the code looked like before I went to Grids:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BogusProgram.DummyUI"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:autoUIsettings="clr-namespace:BogusProgram.Resources"
         xmlns:converters ="clr-namespace:BogusProgram.Converters"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:BogusProgram.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >

<!--UserControl Resources-->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!--Automatic UI Settings-->
    <autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings x:Key="AutomaticUISettings" />

    <!--Enum to Boolean Converter-->
    <converters:EnumBooleanConverter x:Key="enumBooleanConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<!--UserControl Command Bindings-->
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <!--Compare Change of all settings to Last set-->
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>

    <!--Note: Can use individual RoutedCommands per object-->
    <!--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254992/how-can-i-best-handle-wpf-radio-buttons-->
</UserControl.CommandBindings>


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Enable/Disable Automatic UI-->
    <CheckBox Content="Enable Automatic UI" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings.Default}, Path=AutoUIEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" x:Name="AutoUICheckbox" Margin="10,5" />

    <!--Automatic UI Settings-->
    <GroupBox Header="Automatic UI Settings" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,5" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings.Default}, Path=AutoUIEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <!--Set Automatic UI change by value-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,5">
                    <Label Content="Change UI By:     " />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings.Default}, Path=ChangUIby, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="35" x:Name="CHuiBy" 
                        TextChanged="CHuiBy_TextChanged" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" />
                </StackPanel>


                <!--Set when to change UI-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,5">
                    <Label Content="Change UI Every:" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings.Default}, Path=WaitPeriod, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="35" x:Name="CHuiEv"
                        TextChanged="CHuiEv_TextChanged" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" />

                    <!--Change UI Every Help-->
                    <Button Content="[?]" Command="{Binding ShowCHuiEvHelp}" Margin="5" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="10">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>


                <!--Change UI for-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,5" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings.Default}, Path=RunPeriodEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                    <Label Content="Change UI For:   " />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings.Default}, Path=RunPeriod, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="35" x:Name="RunFor"
                        TextChanged="RunFor_TextChanged" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" />

                    <!--Change UI For Help-->
                    <Button Content="[?]" Command="{Binding ShowCHuiForHelp}" Margin="5" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="10">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>


                <!--Set Max UI value-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,5">
                    <Label Content="Max UI Value:" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings.Default}, Path=MaxUI, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="35" x:Name="MaxUI" 
                        TextChanged="MaxUI_TextChanged" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" />

                    <!--Max UI Value Help-->
                    <Button Content="[?]" Command="{Binding ShowMaxValueHelp}" Margin="5" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="10">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>


                <!--Set Min UI value-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,5">
                    <Label Content="Min UI Value:" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings.Default}, Path=MinUI, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="35" x:Name="MinUI" 
                        TextChanged="MinUI_TextChanged" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" />

                    <!--Min UI Value Help-->
                    <Button Content="[?]" Command="{Binding ShowMinValueHelp}" Margin="5" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="10">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>


                <!--Enable/Disable Max Run Period-->
                <CheckBox Content="Enable Max Run Period" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings.Default}, Path=RunPeriodEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                    Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" x:Name="RunPeriodCheckbox" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
            </Grid>


            <!--If Max UI is Met-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{StaticResource AutomaticUISettings}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!--Header-->
                    <Label Content="If Max UI value is met" />

                    <!--Max UI Value Met Help-->
                    <Button Content="[?]" Command="{Binding ShowMaxValueMetHelp}" Margin="5" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="10">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>

                <!--Options-->
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMaxUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MaxMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Stop}" 
                            Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Stop" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMaxUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MaxMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RollOver}" 
                            Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Roll over to zero" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMaxUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MaxMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RollOvertoMin}" 
                            Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Roll over to Min UI value" Margin="10,0" />
            </StackPanel>


            <!--If Min UI is Met-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{StaticResource AutomaticUISettings}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!--Header-->
                    <Label Content="If Min UI value is met" />

                    <!--Min UI Value Met Help-->
                    <Button Content="[?]" Command="{Binding ShowMinValueMetHelp}" Margin="5" Foreground="DarkCyan" FontSize="10">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>

                <!--Options-->
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMinUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MinMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Stop}"
                        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Stop" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMinUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MinMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RollOver}" 
                        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Roll over to 255" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMinUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MinMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RollOvertoMax}" 
                        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Roll over to Max UI value" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMinUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MinMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RolltoValue}" 
                        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Roll over to calculated Value" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetMinUI" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.MinMetRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=InvertUI}" 
                        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Change UI in inverse direction" Margin="10,0" />
            </StackPanel>

            <!--Max Run Period-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static autoUIsettings:AutoUISettings.Default}, Path=RunPeriodEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                DataContext="{StaticResource AutomaticUISettings}">

                <!--Header-->
                <Label Content="If Run Period is met" />

                <!--Options-->
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetRunPeriod" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.RunPeriodRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Stop}" 
                        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Stop" Margin="10,0" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="MeetRunPeriod" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.RunPeriodRadio, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Run}" 
                        Command="{x:Static views:SetupAutoUI.CompareSettings}" Content="Continue to running at last UI" Margin="10,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="Apply" Command="{Binding ApplyAutoUI}" Padding="5" Margin="10,0" IsEnabled="{Binding AutoUIChanged}" />
        <Button Content="Close/Cancel" Command="{Binding CloseAutoUI}" Padding="5" Margin="10,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why are you overriding it's `ControlTemplate`? I'm pretty sure that's the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: You confirmed if the `DataContext` of this `Button` is set right to where the `ShowMaxValueMetHelp` command is defined? Use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to check it up if you haven't already.

Comment: @Omribitian - I got rid of the template modification to have it be just a regular button, and didn't make a difference. I did that before I posted my question.

Comment: @Viv - I copied working buttons in place of this one, and made no difference.

Comment: @Bluto copying Button's into this place which worked elsewhere does not validate `DataContext` being set correctly, if `DataContext` being set is wrong, I'd expect both `Button`'s to not work at this scope.

Comment: Sorry @Viv. The buttons and their commands are in the same DataContext, and the same UserControl, as you can read above. Doesn't matter what button I put in ther, with any modified template.

Comment: @Bluto I cannot reproduce this issue, Can you put a sample application together that shows this problem and attach it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

actually you have to understand the diffrence between **ContentTemplate** and **ControlTemplate** of a Control( here it is Button ).

- **ContentTemplate** says how your control content should look like with keeping all the events ans properties of the control.
- **ControlTemplate** says how your control got overridden means it loose its all properties ans events so you have ti define them separately.means you have change the control actually.i think that you does not want.

so in place of changing **ControlTemplate** change its **ContentTemplate** like this.

```
<Button> 
 <Button.ContentTemplate>
  <DataTemplate> 

   <contentpresenter/>  // place code how your button should look like

 </DataTemplate> 
 </Button.ContentTemplate>
<Button>
```

Comment: I got rid of the template modification to have it be just a regular button, and didn't make a difference. I did that before I posted my question.

Comment: is your ShowMaxValueMetHelp Command is in the AutomaticUISettings datacontext ?

Comment: Yes, I have other buttons above in the same datacontext, and they work fine. I tried to copy them down to this area in the code and it didn't help.